# Why is it that after Mirroring a Mesh, it shows up as Transparent in Unity?

Tags: mesh, unity, mirror

so I'm having a weird problem. Basically I modeled a Shoe (the one on our Right). Then I of course saved time by deciding to select that shoe, Shift+D (Duplicate), and Ctrl+M (Mirror) it on X axis.

This looks like it totally worked fine and normal within Blender. However, whenever I imported it into Unity, the mirrored shoe shows up 'underneath' the character's foot (shown below).

Does anyone know why this might have happened?

[image]

Foot over left shoe in Unity

[image: Shoe looks solid in Blender!]

Foot under left shoe in Blender

I should clarify that both do Export with solid materials; it's just that one decides to go under the foot while the other goes over. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The normals were inverted** when you mirrored your mesh. Unity has probably backface culling enabled which make the faces transparent when viewed from the wrong side.

In Blender, you can see face orientations by enabling `Face orientation` in the `Overlays` :

[image]

[image]

The front side of the faces are displayed blue and the backside are red. Blender has also backface culling option and if you enable it, the faces will become transparent when viewed from the back side :

[image]

[image]

Here you can see through the second cube because his faces are turned inside out.

To fix your problem go back to Blender. Select your shoes, go to Edit Mode, select everything whit `A` and press `ALT`+ `N` then `Recalculate Outside`. Then, re-export your mesh.

It should fix it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'm Glad I helped.